# How to setModel while simulating a Brownian motion in R

Tags: r, model, package

[image]i'm simulating a Brownian motion by using setModel

library(yiuma)
mod1 <- setModel(drift = "-3*x", diffusion = "1/(1+x^2+t)", solve.variable = c("x"))

but R is telling me this message:
Error: could not find function "setModel"

How can i do to find a way to simulate my model while solving the problem of "setModel"

Comment: spelling maybe? `yuima`

Comment: yes it is yuima but even in using yuima it doesn't work at all. Still telling me  Error: could not find function "setModel"

Comment: Works for me. Did you do `library(yuima)` before running the `setModel` commands again?

Comment: I get no error. You need to provide system details, including complete transcripot when you run that code and  `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: ok,  by the looks of it `Matrix` isn't getting installed. Try `install.packages("Matrix")`, but it might be worth installing a newer version of R

Comment: I inserted now my codes in the question box. You can see that it is always telling me the same.